# The meaning of Orthogonal, Complete and Orthonormal Functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am Studying Quantum Mechanics, and from the properties of the solution of Schrodinger's Equation inside the infinite well, is that they are:

1) Mutually orthogonal
2) Orthonormal
3) Complete

What is the mathematical and physical meaning of these properties, and how to use them in applications?!

Comment: I'd say try Wikipedia, but Wikipedia's math articles are traditionally layman-hostile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutually orthogonal means $\langle\psi_i \mid \psi_j\rangle = 0$ unless $i = j$.

Orthonormal is more specific, meaning $\langle\psi_i \mid \psi_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ (the Kronecker delta).

Complete means that the solutions span the space.  Either alternatively or as a consequence (depending on what you define and what you derive), it means
$\sum_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ is the identity operator.

**EDIT**
Adding physical interpretation per OP's comment.

The "orthogonal part" means that there is no probability of measuring state $j$ immediately after measuring state $i$.  Using $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ to represent spin up and spin down (respectively) of an electron with respect to some fixed axis, then $\langle+|-\rangle = 0$ tells you that if you measure once at get spin down and then measure again you'll also get spin down.  More precisely, it's the fact that the complex norm of this is 0 since that's what actually gets interpreted as probability in QM. This assumes no intervening measurement of some other quantity that might change the state.

In contrast consider the singlet state
$$ |s\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|+\rangle - |-\rangle)$$
where you have an equal chance of measuring spin up or spin down since
$$ \|\langle+|s\rangle\|^2 = \|\langle-|s\rangle\|^2 = 1/2$$

The "normal" part makes the state compatible with the interpretation of the complex norm of the wave function as a probability distribution. This is stronger than needed to meet this interpretation since any complex number with norm 1 would work for this - Choosing the normalization such that you get 1 has the additional benefit of simplifying calculations, like the one above for computing, e.g., $\langle +|s\rangle$.

Comment: and what is the physical meaning of orthonormality?

Comment: @MohamedAyman I edited my answer to address the physical meaning.